# Angular get data from providers

Tags: angular

i need to console the data in component fetch it from provider. its showing this error when im using subscribe TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Im fetching like this in home.html

```
  this.api.getSamad(this.company_id).subscribe(data=> console.log (data));
```

provider

```
public getSamad(company_id: any){
this.company_id = company_id;
this.url = 'url.com?offset=0&limit=10&company_id='+this.company_id;

 this.clientData = this.httpClient.get<any>(this.url).
 subscribe(data => {
 console.log(data);
         this.spinner.hide();

         this.data1 = data.records;
         this.data1.forEach(d => this.policy_id.add(d.policy_id));
         console.log(this.userFilter.policy_id);
  }
```

i want to show data in home.html can any one please tell how ill show data of provider in home.ts console thanks

Comment: You have to return the observable. IE: `return this.httpClient.get....` Also, you want to pipe like this: `return this.httpClient.get(...).pipe(map(yourCallbackMethod => ....)` If you don't return an observable from the api method, you cannot subscribe to it.

Comment: can you help in code ? i replace <any> with <Observable> still not working

Comment: There is not really enough code in your question for me to post a full answer, but I'll post some code on jsfiddle for you to try: https://jsfiddle.net/c2ftvd18/

Comment: yes i try with same way but its still showing same error of subscribe is undefined

Comment: Can you post a working reproducible example. A stackblitz would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the observable inside your `getSamad` method, and don't subscribe to it there. Your method doesn't return anything that's why it's showing that error.

```
public getSamad(company_id: any){
  this.company_id = company_id;
  this.url = 'url.com?offset=0&limit=10&company_id='+this.company_id;
  return this.httpClient.get<any>(this.url);
}
```

Then you can subscribe to it in your component, put inside that subscribe what was in your `getSamad`'s subscribe.